# How to extend timeout for tests in circleci?

Tags: java, scala, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

Im running some tests in circleci and some of the tests are taking longer then 10 min cause its ui tests that run on a headless browser that Im installing in my circle.yml

How can I extend the time of the timeout?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `timeout` modifier in your config as explained in this doc:
https://circleci.com/docs/configuration#modifiers

Here is an example doubling the default 600s to 1200s:

```
commands:
    - /bin/bash build_scripts/deploy_to_eb.sh:
        timeout: 1200
```

Cheers

Comment: default is 600s - (not milliseconds) 
 - https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#modifiers

Comment: @AaronMahan could you let me know what more do you need so that I can add to the answer

Answer (score 14):

You can add the `timeout` modifier to your command to increase the timeout beyond the default 600 seconds (10min).

For example, if you ran a test called my-test.sh, you could do the following:

```
test:
  override:
    - ./my-test.sh:
        timeout: 900
```

Note that the command ends with a colon (:), with the modifier on the next line, double-indented (4 spaces instead of 2).

Reference: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration#modifiers

Comment: Note that the timeout command should be indented 4 spaces from the command above it, according to the specified documentation. This is referred to as a "double indentation" in the docs, which assumes you are using a two-space indentation.

Comment: Thanks @AaronMahan.

Comment: I haven't personally tried it. I'd assume that as long as the trailing colon and the right indentation is used, it'll work but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using Circle CI 2.0, the syntax is `no_output_timeout`:

```
- run:
    name: Running Tests
    command: ./my-test.sh
    no_output_timeout: 20m
```

More details: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run